# Android: Can I retrieve the step data (number of steps taken) from the Mi Fit app?

Tags: android, wearables

I am trying to work with the number of steps taken by a user but cannot seem to access the data from my Mi Band 4. I do have a workaround but that requires 2 other applications. Is there any way to access the step data?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to sync your Mi Band with Google Fit and use Google Fit API to get the step data (and other data). Hope that helps.
[Google Fit Steps API](https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/read-daily-step-total)

Comment: That is the workaround I wrote about, but I'd need both Mi Fit and Google Fit Apps for it, right? Or can I directly sync my band with Google Fit? Also, thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you find any solution other than gadget bridge?